# Computing infinitesimal generator for a jump process with continuous component

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to show that the infinitesimal generator of the following process

$$ dS_t = (\alpha S_{t-}+\beta )dt + (\gamma S_{t-}+\delta)dX_t,$$

where $X_t$ is a $(\lambda,G)$-compound Poisson process (that is $X_t=\sum_{k=1}^{N_t}Z_k$, $N_t$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$, and $Z_k\sim G, supp(G)=\mathbb{R}$) is given by

$$\mathcal{L}(f)(x)=(\alpha x+\beta)f'(x)+\lambda \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(x+\gamma xz+\delta z)-f(x)]dG(z)$$

This is Proposition 8.6.7.1 from Jeanblanc, Chesney and Yor (2009) "Mathematical Methods in Financial Markets."

I was hoping if someone could clarify to me one of the steps in the proof of this result. The details are below.

---

The approach in the book is to apply path-by-path Stieltjes integration to write,

$$ f(S_t)-f(x) = \int_0^tf'(S_{s-})(\alpha S_{s-}+\beta)ds+\sum_{0\geq s\geq t} \Delta(f(S_t))$$
and then take the expectations of this expression to obtain

$$ \mathbb{E}^x[f(S_t)-f(x)]= \mathbb{E}^x\left[\int_0^tf'(S_{s-})(\alpha S_{s-}+\beta)ds+\sum_{0\geq s\geq t} \Delta(f(S_t))\right]\\
=\mathbb{E}^x\left[\int_0^tf'(S_s)(\alpha S_{s-}+\beta)ds\right]+\mathbb{E}^x\left[\sum_{0\geq s\geq t} f(S_{s-}+
\Delta S_s)-f(S_{s-})\right]$$

Up to this point, everything is clear. It is easy to show that the first term will converge to $(\alpha x+\beta)f'(x)$ when we divide by $t$ and take the limit as $t\downarrow 0$.

**The step I do not understand is the following**. The authors write:

$$ \mathbb{E}^x\left[\sum_{0\geq s\geq t} f(S_{s-}+\Delta S_s)- f(S_{s-})\right] \\ 
=\mathbb{E}^x\left[ \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)z)  -f(S_{s-})dG(z)\lambda dt\right] (*)$$

Why this equality follows? How to justify it? Or is there a way to proceed alternatively?

---

I tried writing this sum as
$$ \mathbb{E}^x\left[\sum_{0\geq s\geq t} f(S_{s-}+\Delta S_s)-f(S_{s-})\right]=\mathbb{E}^x\left[ \int_0^t f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)Z)  -f(S_{s-})dN_t\right]$$
I can then rewrite this expectations as
$$\mathbb{E}^x\left[ \int_0^t f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)Z)  -f(S_{s-})dN_t\right] = \mathbb{E}^x\left[ \int_0^t f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)Y)  -f(S_{s-})d(N_t-\lambda t)\right] \\
+ \mathbb{E}^x\left[ \int_0^t f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)Z)  -f(S_{s-})d(\lambda t)\right]
= \mathbb{E}^x\left[ \int_0^t f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)Z)  -f(S_{s-})d(N_t-\lambda t)\right]
+ \\\lambda \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)z)  -f(S_{s-}) dG(z)ds$$
So if I could argue that the expectations of the first term is 0 I would be done. But the integrand is right continuous, and so I do not think it is a martingale.

I went very carefully through the book today, and it is hinted that they use a random measure, of the form $\mu=\sum_n \delta_{T_n,Y_n}$ and claim that
$$ \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)z)  -f(S_{s-})d(\mu(dz,ds)-\lambda G(ds))$$
is a local martingale. But I am not sure how to use that fact.

Comment: "[...] does not seem to be a martingale" Why not? The process $N_t-\lambda t$ is a martingale and therefore the stochastic integral $\int_0^t H(s) \, d(N_s-\lambda s)$ is a martingale for any nicely integrable and measurable $H$.

Comment: @saz Thank you so much for your response. Shouldn't the integrand be left continuous for the integral wrt $(N_t-\lambda t)$ to be a martingale? Also, I made a mistake, I should have arrived at the following integral $\int_{0}^t f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)Z)-f(S_{s-})d(N_t-\lambda t) $ rather than $\int_{0}^t\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(S_{s-}+(\gamma S_{s-}+\delta)z)-f(S_{s-})dG(z)d(N_t-\lambda t) $. I updated the question accordingly with some additional context. Do you have any idea how to deal with the updated integral? I am most likely missing something trivial...

Comment: Why do you think that the integrand is right-continuous? Since $t \mapsto S_t$ is càdlàg (=right continuous and left-hand limits) it follows that $t \mapsto S_{t-}$ is càglàd (=left-continuous and right-hand limits).

Comment: @saz But the integrand is of the form $f(S_t)−f(S_{t−})$ since $(\gamma S_{s−}+\delta )Y$ is the jump of the process $S_t$. Isn't then the difference right continuous?

Comment: I just had once more a look at your computations, and I think that the very first equation (when you rewrite the sums) is actually wrong... the problem is that you are using the same $Z$ over the whole time which is not what is happening in reality (because the $k$-th jump height $Z_k$ will, in general, depend on $k$)). I suppose the only way is indeed to use the random measure which you are mentioning at the very end of your answer.

Comment: Regarding your previous comment: We have $S_t = S_{t-} + \Delta N_t \Delta S_t$; as you say yourself the left-hand side is right-continuous... to get a left-continuous integrand the idea is to write $$S_t = S_{t-} + z \Delta S_t$$ where $z = \Delta N_t$. Note that for fixed $z$ the expression $t \mapsto S_{t-} + z \Delta S_t$ is left-continuous, and that's exactly the expression which pops up in the stochastic integral.

Comment: @saz You are, of course, right about $Z$. I guess you I could write it as $Z_{N_s}1_{\Delta N_s\neq 0}$ or sth like that. Regarding the integral with respect to the random measure, can we conclude that its expectation is 0? That would close the argument used in the book.

Comment: (Brief remark: In previous comment it is suppsed to read $\Delta X_t$ instead of $\Delta N_t$; can't edit it any more.... but it seems that you understand what I meant.) Yes, the integral w.r.t to the random measure is a martingale, and hence it has expectation zero.

Comment: @saz Thanks a lot for your time! I am not very familiar with random measures so it is not immediately obvious to me that this integral is a martingale. But will try to see if I can figure this out.